# Kubuntu does not always boot after Win10 update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount, kubuntu

I have a system with Windows 7, Windows 10 and Kubuntu 16.10 in a tripple-boot mode. After recently updating the neglected Windows 10 my Ubuntu does not allways boot.
Sometimes it starts without any problems, sometimes it seems to have some problems with the partitions.

At first there are some jobs running for 1:30 minutes:

```
Started Initial Check File System Quotas.
(1 of 4) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2uuid-ef...
```

After this has finished it seems like partitions could not be found:

```
[  OK  ] Started Initial Check File System Quotas
[  OK  ] Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using ...
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuif-df044add\x2d6a90\x2d4673\x2dbe3d\x2d1863e600846c.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /home.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /home/prog.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/df044add-6a90-4673-be3d-1863e600846c
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c311c811\x2d9b69\x2d4009\x2d90a4\x2d7befc02da893
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/c311c811-9b69-4009-90a4-7befc02da893.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e2ff1401\x2d52b2\x2d453d\x2db4d0\x2dd73720ba51a0
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/e2ff1401-52b2-453d-b4d0-d73720ba51a0
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Starting Enable support for additional executable binary fomats...
[  OK  ] Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed...
```

... followed by some other OK prints finalizing in:

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue): _
```

Control-D results in nothing but a not responding console. The system logs don't show any error or unusual behaviour.

If I start Ubuntu from the **recovery mode** (without performing any other actions in it) it boots without any problems.

I thought this might be an error in `fstab`, but it looks okay to me.
`/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=b3d25587-e1eb-43b2-a028-dd8f56f26f59 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro         0       1
UUID=0A12-AB93                            /boot/efi       vfat    defaults                  0       2
UUID=df044add-6a90-4673-be3d-1863e600846c /home           ext4    defaults                  0       2
UUID=e2ff1401-52b2-453d-b4d0-d73720ba51a0 /home/prog      ext4    defaults                  0       2
UUID=c311c811-9b69-4009-90a4-7befc02da893 none            swap    sw                        0       0
```

`lsblk -o NAME,UUID,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE`:

```
NAME   UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT FSTYPE
sdd
├─sdd1 c311c811-9b69-4009-90a4-7befc02da893 [SWAP]     swap
└─sdd2 e2ff1401-52b2-453d-b4d0-d73720ba51a0 /home/prog ext4
sdb
├─sdb1
├─sdb2 FA3CC2643CC21B8F                                ntfs
└─sdb3 df044add-6a90-4673-be3d-1863e600846c /home      ext4
sr0
sdc
└─sdc1 55D123D9E79ABF54                                ntfs
sda
├─sda1 0A12-AB93                            /boot/efi  vfat
├─sda2
├─sda3 0C401616401606DC                                ntfs
├─sda5 01D2642C29AB5A80                                ntfs
└─sda6 b3d25587-e1eb-43b2-a028-dd8f56f26f59 /          ext4
```

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this problem?

---

Update: trying [Ubuntu boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) did not work. Here is the summary: http://paste2.org/y2k0xMa5

Comment: Two suggestions. When booting into Ubuntu, have FSTAB mount the Windows partitions in read-only mode. Second, to be doubly sure, disable Windows fast-boot. Windows fast-boot could be causing a problem if not disabled.  
Tutorials/Tips "How to disable fast startup in Windows 10". http://linuxbsdos.com/2016/06/05/how-to-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10/

Comment: Unfortunately both suggestions did not work. The windows partitions haven't even been listed in `fstab` before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my solution was to **reinstall** Kubuntu. I have tried everything else I could find in any forum.

I have used the partition tables above to safely identify my partitions.

Only *root* (`/`) sda6 and *swap* had to be formated during the installation. All other partitions (and the data on it) could be reused.

The packages could be reinstalled by first saving the list via

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '!/deinstall|purge|hold/ {print $1}' > packages.list.save
```

and reinstalling them via

```
xargs -a "packages.list.save" sudo apt-get install
```